# Using Dynamic SQL in a trigger to identify changes

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm in the process of building a brand-new database, and want every table I create to have a corresponding audit table which would track any data changes.

In order to avoid having to hard-code every table column, what I would like to do is use Dynamic SQL to review each column in the table (with the exception of the Identity column) and work out whether or not the column has been changed, using the Inserted and Deleted tables to do so.  By doing that, I could then theoretically add columns to the tables without having to re-create the triggers associated with the tables.

Is such a thing possible or am I running down a blind alley?

Comment: Just use a "System-Versioned Temporal Table".

Comment: You can but its very inefficient, in your case all commands except for `SELECT` will be impacted. _Hard-Coding_ in most cases with SQL is actually a good thing, don't fight it, even if the schema changes frequently. Use dynamic SQL or other scripting languages to write the SQL to rebuild your audit triggers. I put mine into a stored procedure, but have scripted it via T4 templates in the application layer as well.

Comment: As @DaleK suggests, Temporal Tables are built in to SQL Server and do all the hard work for you, so unless you need something not supported by system versioning (history tables must reside in the same database, all columns are included) it makes perfect sense to implement, especially in a brand new database.